# Function returning object type

Tags: typescript

When I define an object in Typescript, it can not have properties not specified in its types:

However, when I define a function which returns an object, this object can have more properties than the ones specified in its types:

```js
type Style = { color: string };
type IFunction = () => Style

const foo: Style = {
    color: "red",
    toto:"blue" // error yeah :)
}

const bar: IFunction = () => ({
    color: "red",
    toto:"blue"
})
```

How can I do to specify that I only want to return the properties specified in my object type, and I want to raise an error whenever some extra property is added ?

[Typescript example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Style%20%3D%20%7B%20color%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20IFunction%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20Style%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Style%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toto%3A%22blue%22%20%2F%2F%20error%20yeah%20%3A)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20IFunction%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toto%3A%22blue%22%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%0D%0A%7D))

EDIT: I should have specified that I would prefer not to tell explicitly the returning type like that:

```js
const bar: IFunction = ():Style => ({
    color: "red",
    toto:"blue"
})
```

Indeed, I want to use this code for every React component in my App and it's going to be really cumbersome to specify this type every single time

Comment: How complex of a returned object are you wanting it to verify? In this simple case it's possible, but a object constructed through more complex means wouldn't be trivial to verify, and may not even be possible if it depends on user input.

Comment: @Carcigenicate In my real case, my object type `Style` got more than 100 properties. However the construction of the object is as simple as the one in the question: ```const bar: IFunction = () => ({
 // 100 properties here
})```

Comment: Try changing `const bar: IFunction = () => ({` to `const bar: IFunction = (): Style => ({`. Here i added that this function explicitly returns `type Style`, so it will throw an error in the function. Typescript does a bit of inference here. https://medium.com/@lemoine.benoit/why-does-typescript-sometimes-fails-to-type-check-extra-properties-fd230ebbc295

Comment: @davidhu2000 Thanks for your article :) Your solution work indeed great, but since the code I'm showing is going to be used a lot of time in my codebase (it is for styling every React component in my App), I'd like to avoid to repeat adding this type in every single object definition. It's going to be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for that doesn't involve doing *something* for every place where the issue appears now?  There are tricks to simuate [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) in TypeScript, but they all involve some work where you want them to be enforced.  If a single `: Style` is too much for you, I doubt anything else will be easier.

Comment: Yeah basically after investigating a bit, my question is about simulating `Exact` type like Flow has, where I won't need to repeat myself. It's not a single `:Style`, but thousands ones on the current basecode

Comment: I mean it's a single change in each of the (apparently thousands of) uses.  There is no concrete type `Exact<Style>` which acts like what you want.  At best there are generics and helper functions.  But they will all require you change the code from `const foo: IFunction = () => {...}` to something like (say) `const foo = strictIFunction(()=>{...})`.  If that's too much, then I don't think there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, say explicitly about the function return type

```
type Style = { color: string };
type IFunction = () => Style;

const foo: Style = {
    color: "red",
    toto: "blue" // error yeah :)
};

const bar: IFunction = (): Style => ({
    color: "red",
    toto: "blue" // no error ??????
});
```

`Property excessive checks` won't work until explicitly say the type in below scenario as well(*as of TypeScript 3.4*), In Typescript 3.5 improved excess Property checks in union types

```
function checkStyle(style: Style) {}

checkStyle({
    color: "red",
    toto: "blue" // cast to Style, no error yeah :(
} as Style);

let foo3 = {
    color: "red",
    toto: "blue" // no type annotation and no error yeah :(
};

checkStyle(foo3);
```

The reason for not throwing an error is **type widening** when TypeScript checks whether or not one object type is assignable to another object type. As long as `color` property exists on object TypeScript will be happy.

Comment: Hello Raja, thanks for your answer :) Please read OP, I've edited my post after a comment made @davidhu2000, sorry for that